# checking for valid input using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

How to check for valid and invalid input in python? My valid input looks like :
**a "name" (100,20) (7,8) (10,12)**

How can I check for this using regex functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some expression, similar to,

```
^[a-z]\s"\w+"\s(?:\(\d+\s*,\d+\s*\)\s*){3}$
```

or with less boundaries,

```
^[a-z]\s"\w+"\s+(?:\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)\s*){3}$
```

for instance, you can likely do so.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Txsht/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = """
a "name" (100,20) (7,8) (10,12)
b "some_other_name_1" ( 100, 20) (7, 8) (10, 12)
Z b "some_other_name_1" ( 100, 20) (7, 8) (10, 12)

"""

expression = r'^[a-z]\s"\w+"\s+(?:\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)\s*){3}$'

print(re.findall(expression, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['a "name" (100,20) (7,8) (10,12)', 'b "some_other_name_1" ( 100, 20) (7, 8) (10, 12)']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3Txsht/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/3Txsht/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---